# Is there a Stack Exchange site for asking questions about or discussing cars?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am wondering if there is any Stack Exchange site available for asking questions related to different cars.

Because we use them every day.

Comment: Related to cars how? There's certainly the [vehicle repair site](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: Useful list: https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: Related: [Where to ask driving questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270184/where-to-ask-driving-questions-has-a-site-including-driving-questions-ever-been) - answers and question discuss failed attempts to start an "On the road" site for general motorists' questions and a [failed "Cars" proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84505/cars) which sounds like what you're asking about. That was two years ago though, maybe there's something new

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're talking about car maintenance, then there is [Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Motor Vehicles Stack Exchange is for mechanics and DIY-enthusiast
>   owners of cars, trucks, and motorcycles.
>
> Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and
>   their accessories, internal combustion engines, even in applications
>   other than automotive so long as the question is related to engine or
>   engine accessories.

But please check the help center for information before you post a question -- I'm not a regular user there so I can't say for sure what you can ask about. I've quoted part of the /on-topic section of the site.