# Where can I ask driving questions? Has a site including driving questions ever been attempted?

Tags: support, area-51, site-recommendation

Is there (or has there been) any SE site where I can ask questions about driving techniques, car handling, etc.?

I couldn't find anything in the list of sites or on Area 51. Close misses include [travel.SE, which has a "driving" tag](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/driving), but which I believe understandably limits it to driving-related issues in long distance trips (e.g., driving abroad, rental cars, etc.), and [mechanics.SE, which doesn't allow driving questions](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-driving-questions-on-topic). There's a ["cars" Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84505/cars), but it's for car enthusiasts, not about driving, and [it looks to be going nowhere/duped to mechanics.SE](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22278/mechanics-se-overlap).

It'd be remarkable if we had sites for [cyclists](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/) and [pilots](http://aviation.stackexchange.com), and [a proposal for a boating site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90499/boating), but not drivers or motorists. I was expecting to find something like a failed "Motorists" beta; I'm surprised to find nothing at all.

---

Here are a few example questions I'd be interested in seeing authoritative, fact-based, SE-style answers to—where people I know and sources I've tried online give a variety of contradictory or weakly reasoned answers. For some of them I've even had contradictory answers from different driving instructors:

- Is there any harm in changing gear to "2" or "L" in an automatic while moving at a speed suitable for that gear?
- Is there any difference between driving an automatic in "L" and "D" when you won't exceed 5-10 mph (e.g., up a very steep hill)?
- Can an automatic engine stall? (and if it can, how to safely get going again without a clutch?)
- Is it ever safe to coast while moving downhill, e.g., at very low speeds? (in countries where it's legal)
- In regions where drivers expect the horn to be used during ordinary overtaking, at what point during overtaking will sounding the horn most reduce the risk of collisions?
- Why does driving a manual car (usually) use less fuel than an automatic with the same number of gears?
- What signs should a driver of an automatic look for that their transmission might be failing?
- Does driving an automatic at below the 1st gear tick-over speed by applying the footbrake cause wear to the breaks? (or does it behave like easing off the clutch in a manual?)
- Do "reverse" and "first" gears always have the exact same speed:power ratio?
- Is there any type of incident where a rear-facing dashcam could avoid a driver being unfairly blamed? (which wouldn't be presumed in their favour anyway)

---

Update: it sounds like there isn't one, so I'm expanding this question to has any such site ever been attempted? I know that failed sites are often deleted from Area 51, which might be why I'm not finding one. Also, might anyone be interested in starting one "driving and motoring", maybe, covering all aspects of car ownership and use except those covered by mechanics.SE? (I'm not experienced enough to do it myself.)

Comment: "in which countries" isn't going to be ontopic anywhere, it's a list question. If you are traveling in country X, and someone beeped at you while passing, and you were wondering what that meant, you could ask **about country X only** on travel.

Comment: also, questions related to saving fuel might be on topic on Sustainability

Comment: @KateGregory You're right, I've changed that one to a different related genuine question I have that is more "driving" than "travel"

Comment: A few of these questions would be on topic on [vehicle maintenance](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) e.g. *What signs should a driver of an automatic look for that their transmission might be failing?*

Comment: [right here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243460/165773)?

Comment: @Chenmunka is there any info about why it failed or what happened? I can't see it on Area51 - is there any way to learn from its experience?

Comment: @Chenmunka cool, I realised that this was a seperate question which I think hadn't been asked before, so [I asked it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270250/is-there-any-way-to-see-deleted-area51-proposals-to-learn-from-what-went-wrong?lq=1), and if you find a way you can post it there as an answer

Answer (score 9):

There was a site proposed two years ago called "On the Road" that was described as:

> Proposed Q&A site for everybody affected by road traffic. This site should be used to ask/answer questions on a wide variety of traffic issues, ranging from local traffic question to question addressing driving amongst traffic abroad.

With 25 followers and 4 eligible "example questions", it was closed after [1+ year in Definition](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5798/closing-a-proposal-after-1-year-in-definition-or-commitment). If you have reason to believe this can work a second time around (typically coming up with an existing community who wants to build this thing), you are certainly welcome to try again.

Comment: I haven't seen too many resources aimed towards driving instructor skill development (and for the few that pop up on google, such resources are aimed towards those within the Great Britain Demographic - there's next to nothing that's meant for those located in North America, much less stateside.)

Answer (score 5):

[Robert Cartaino♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino) kindly emailed me some of the content of the now-deleted **On the Road** proposal.

It's pretty hard to see exactly what went wrong - looking at the stats and questions, I guess it never really grabbed or excited any community of experts. I didn't see any discussions in what I was sent; but here's the top voted example questions. These might be relevant to anyone thinking of trying again:

- +11 Which has a higher accident rate - roundabouts or traffic lights?
- +10 How to suddenly stop car when raining ?
- +10 Does sleep deprivation have the same effects on driving as drinking?
- +10 Can I have multiple drivers licenses from different countries?
- +10 What are the differences between the EU and USA regarding yielding at a cross road? [comments suggested it's too broad; it might be on topic at travel.se]
- +9 What is the optimal driving style on highways to prevent traffic jams?
- +6 Can you increase highway capacity by applying different road markers? [seems to be creeping towards town planning]

...and various others along similar lines.

Many of these seem a bit basic (could be answered from Highway Code or similar), which maybe supports my suspicion that to work, a "Driving and motorists" type SE site would need to aggressively target the experts and professionals (driving instructors, taxi drivers, etc), and engage them as the core question-answerers by actively seeking out interesting advanced-level and professional-driver-career content.

Then, it can allow everything from learner questions and car enthusiast questions to career questions around taxi licensing etc, and there will be a core rump of experts who can enforce quality.

This might be a challenge because I don't think there's much overlap between professional drivers and SE's current demographics. Aviation intersects via flight simulation enthusiasts, bicycles intersects via urban professionals/tech-hipsters, etc, but in my experience, driving professionals are rarely "computer-y", while SE tends to be disproportionately white-collar.