# Add a list of followed proposal sites which got deleted?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, area-51

I created some proposals on Area 51, and I (obviously) followed them all. Unfortunately, they all got deleted for not meeting the three-day requirements. Whenever I return to my Area 51 profile the proposals that I followed, but were deleted, are not shown.

So, should we add a list of followed proposal sites in the user's profile which got deleted on Area 51?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270250/is-there-a-way-to-see-deleted-area-51-proposals-to-learn-from-what-went-wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is little to no benefit of enabling users to see deleted proposals in any area. Pretty much the only good reason a user would ever have to view details about a deleted proposal is to know which ones got deleted so they can potentially propose it again. But we no longer support that workflow, and users proposing the same thing over again is something we'd like to explicitly discourage, not make easier. To quote Robert Cartaino in a now-deleted post:

> Unfortunately, subjects re-posted with the same claims of vague or unsubstantiated support are no longer supported by this process. Area 51 is not the place to find an audience. When you submit a proposal for a new site, you are implicitly agreeing to the instructions in that form which state:
>
> > When you submit a proposal for a site, it is generally assumed you have access to an audience to build it. Area 51 cannot find that community for you.

Comment: Interesting. Please also decline [this duplicate request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270250/is-there-any-way-to-see-deleted-area51-proposals-to-learn-from-what-went-wrong) then, even though Robert gave a different answer there. (Guess there was change of mind in the years that passed.)