# Is this possible to remove a moderator status tag if I change my question?

Tags: support, edits, moderator-tags

I asked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317858/add-a-list-of-followed-proposal-sites-which-got-deleted) here on MSE a while ago, as a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), which later got rejected by a moderator. After doing edits to most of my questions, I thought it would be a good idea to change the original tag into a [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag and to delete the [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) tag too.

However, when I went to edit the tags, it showed this error:

[image: Moderator tag error]

That basically meant I wasn't able to remove the moderator tag, and I had to add it back, even though I switched the whole topic of the question and all of the other tags.

How can I remove a moderator tag, do I have to ask a moderator to remove it?

Comment: _“even though I switched the whole topic of the question”_ — you’re not supposed to do that. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: @Xufox I thought of that, but if I asked a new question it would basically also be a duplicate to my original one and another question too.

Comment: @Devealte questions tagged `support` are very rarely, if ever, duplicates of separate questions tagged `feature-request`. Support questions are asking if there *already is* a way to do something. Feature requests are asking to *add a new feature* that doesn't exist

Comment: The [question that you have linked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317858) is here on Meta SE, but you say it is on Meta SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edited question makes answers incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179215/edited-question-makes-answers-incorrect)

Comment: @gnat no, that is totally not a duplicate.

Comment: @ShadowWizard 100k on MSE! Wew lad.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> … wasn't able to remove the moderator tag … even though I switched the whole topic of the question

If you are completely changing the subject of your question, you should just *ask a new question*. Once a question has been asked and answered, it's a bit odd (and perhaps inappropriate) to try and change it to something else in-place.

Moderator tags, as their name suggests, are for moderators only. You cannot add or remove any moderator tags on any questions. But if you *do* have a valid reason to have a moderator tag removed, flag it for moderator attention and select the option "in need of moderator intervention" to explain the situation.